# How to create download progress notification in Oreo?

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-8.0-oreo

I am creating an App which can download a file from the server and display progress in status bar. Here's my code:

```
private void startDownload(final String fileUrl) {
    Thread thread = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            NotificationManagerCompat notificationManagerCompat = NotificationManagerCompat.from(DownloadsActivity.this);

            String contentTitle = "Start downloading";
            Intent notifyIntent = new Intent();
            PendingIntent notifyPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(DownloadsActivity.this, DOWNLOAD_NOTIFICATION_ID, notifyIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

            NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = createNotificationBuilder("downloader_channel");
            notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(notifyPendingIntent);
            notificationBuilder.setTicker("Start downloading from the server");
            notificationBuilder.setOngoing(true);
            notificationBuilder.setAutoCancel(false);
            notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.stat_sys_download);
            notificationBuilder.setContentTitle(contentTitle);
            notificationBuilder.setContentText("0%");
            notificationBuilder.setProgress(100, 0, false);
            notificationManagerCompat.notify(DOWNLOAD_NOTIFICATION_ID, notificationBuilder.build());

            boolean success;
            try {
                String fileName = DownloadUtils.getInstance().getFullFileName(fileUrl);
                File tmpFile = new File(fileName + ".tmp");

                URL url = new URL(fileUrl);
                URLConnection conection = url.openConnection();
                conection.connect();
                int fileLength = conection.getContentLength();

                // input stream to read file - with 8k buffer
                InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream(), 8192);

                // Output stream to write file

                OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(tmpFile);

                byte data[] = new byte[1024];

                long total = 0;
                int count, tmpPercentage = 0;
                while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                    total += count;
                    output.write(data, 0, count);
                    int percentage = (int) ((total * 100) / fileLength);
                    if (percentage > tmpPercentage) {
                        notificationBuilder.setContentText(percentage + "%");
                        notificationBuilder.setProgress(100, percentage, false);
                        notificationManagerCompat.notify(DOWNLOAD_NOTIFICATION_ID, notificationBuilder.build());
                        tmpPercentage = percentage;
                    }
                }

                // flushing output
                output.flush();

                // closing streams
                output.close();
                input.close();

                // rename file but cut off .tmp
                File newFile = new File(fileName);
                success = tmpFile.renameTo(newFile);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                showLog("[Download Error]: " + e.getMessage());
                success = false;
            }
            showLog("Download finished");
            contentTitle = "Downloaded";
            String statusText = success ? "Done" : "Fail";
            int resId = success ? android.R.drawable.stat_sys_download_done : android.R.drawable.stat_notify_error;
            notificationBuilder.setContentTitle(contentTitle);
            notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(resId);
            notificationBuilder.setOngoing(false);
            notificationBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
            notificationBuilder.setContentText(statusText);
            notificationBuilder.setProgress(0, 0, false);
            notificationManagerCompat.notify(DOWNLOAD_NOTIFICATION_ID, notificationBuilder.build());
            isDownloading = false;
        }
    };
    isDownloading = true;
    thread.start();
}

private NotificationCompat.Builder createNotificationBuilder(String channelId) {
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        String channelName = getString(R.string.app_name);
        NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(channelId, channelName, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
        notificationChannel.setLightColor(Color.BLUE);
        notificationChannel.setLockscreenVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PRIVATE);
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        if (notificationManager != null) {
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
        }
    }
    return new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId);
}
```

During the download, it displays progress correctly, but it produces notification sound every percent of progress. One more problem is that when the download finished, it still display the progress and user cannot clear the notification.

*Note: it works fine on older versions. Only happens in Android 8.*

Comment: is this issue solved?

Comment: Same problem here, any solution ?

Comment: I solved it and posted the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it by changing `NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT` to `NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW` while creating notification channel.

Comment: Yes are you right. But I still try to find some good way to show start/progress/completed notifications in my App. If I'll use single channel with IMPORTANCE_LOW it will show without sound vibrate etc. for all notifications like progress and completed too. Right now I have only one idea - use two channels with IMPORTANCE_LOW for progress notifications and IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT for start/completed notifications. But I'm not sure it's right because in App settings user could see two channels for download notifications.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to set Notification IMPORTANCE_LOW you just have set it notification.setAlertOnlyOnce(true). 
And when the download is completed either update the notification with new title or description or you can dismiss this notification and create a new notification using different notification id.

Answer (score -1):

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
        .setOnlyAlertOnce();
```